# How do I execute an orient db batch script?

Tags: orientdb

I'm playing around with orient db for the first time. I have it up and running and I can execute simple scripts via the console.

However, what I really want to do is to use the extra [SQL Batch](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-batch) commands such as 'let.'

e.g. the sample script from the wiki:

```
begin
let account = create vertex Account set name = 'Luke'
let city = select from City where name = 'London'
let edge = create edge Lives from $account to $city
commit retry 100
return $edge
```

If I write a script using those commands, the console throws errors as they don't appear to be supported. The wiki suggests that's because they are only available via the Java and HTTP APIs.

Pasting the content of the script into Studio works fine, but that's a fairly unsatisfactory way to run a simple script.

Am I missing something or is there no way to run a script containing SQL Batch commands via a simple command line instruction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute it from console by using the `script sql` command. Remember to close it by typing `end` on a new line. Example:

```
MacBook-Pro:bin luca$ ./console.sh

OrientDB console v.2.0-SNAPSHOT (build 2539) www.orientechnologies.com
Type 'help' to display all the supported commands.
Installing extensions for GREMLIN language v.2.6.0

orientdb> connect plocal:/temp/databases/ETLDemo admin admin

Connecting to database [plocal:/temp/databases/ETLDemo] with user 'admin'...OK
orientdb {db=ETLDemo}> script sql
[Started multi-line command. Type just 'end' to finish and execute]
orientdb {db=ETLDemo}> begin
orientdb {db=ETLDemo}> let a = create vertex v
orientdb {db=ETLDemo}> commit retry 100
orientdb {db=ETLDemo}> end

Server side script executed in 0,117000 sec(s). Value returned is: V#9:199 v1
orientdb {db=ETLDemo}>
```

Comment: Is it possible to execute sql file agains database? Something similar to `mysql -uroot -p dbName < test.sql` ?

Comment: Not in that way, but it could be a nice feature. Feel free to open a new issue on that. However now you could dynamically create the file by adding the connect to the head of file.

Comment: i want this in php how can i do   i does find any library which supports batch sql in php    my one of main reason of choosing orient db is its batch features but for php i found nothing plz help

Comment: i solved it   [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788146/batch-orientdb-sql-in-php )