# batch orientdb sql in php

Tags: php, sql, orientdb, doctrine-odm

i want this in php how can i do.

I does not find any library which supports batch sql in php my one of main reason of choosing orient db is its batch features but for php i found nothing please help.

I have downloaded `doctrine/odm   as well AntonTerekhov_OrientDB-PHP` from GitHub

I am able run this batch sql from studio:-

```
let $u=select from person where id=1 
let $f=select expand(out(Friend)) from $u[0]
let $a=create vertex posts set created_by=$u[0],text="Hello............lllll"
let $pbedge=create edge POSTED_BY from $a to $u
let $swith=create edge shared_with from $a to $f
commit
return $a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding at many places I decided to create my own Class / Driver for Orient DB.
Here is [Git Hub address](https://github.com/ravinderpayal/OrientDB-PHP)

If someone needs this you are free to use.............
It is able execute both batch and one liner statements/queries/SQL of orientDB

```
<?php
/******** © Fun n Enjoy Internet Ltd ( http://www.funnenjoy.com ) ***********
*
*
/*********** Author: Ravinder Payal ******************
*
*
/***************Date / Time :- 27 Sept 2015 10:25 PM  *****************/


class OrientDb{
    private $host,$username,$password;
    private $connection;
    function __construct($host,$username,$password){
        if(empty($host)){
            throw "Host Address Not Provide";
            }
            if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
            throw "Provide Username / Password. Receaved Empty Strings";
            }
        $this->host=$host;
        $this->username=$username;
        $this->password=$password;
        }
    function connect(){
        $this->connection=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username.":".$this->password);
        curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        }
    function query($db,$query){
            curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_URL, $this->host."/batch/".$db);
            curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
            curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_POST,1);
            $json='{ "transaction" : true,"operations" : [{"type" : "script","language" : "sql","script" : [ "'.$query.'" ]}]}';
            curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Connection: Keep-Alive','Content-Length: ' . strlen($json) ));
            curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
            $result=curl_exec($this->connection);
            $http_code=curl_getinfo($this->connection,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if($http_code!=200){
                            if($http_code==0){
                                 throw new Exception("Host is not accessible.");
                                }
                $result=json_decode($result);
                 throw new Exception("Server returned  ".$result->errors[0]->content." With code ".$result->errors[0]->code);
            }
            $result=json_decode($result);           
            return $result;

        }
    function close(){
        curl_close($this->connection);
        }   
}
```

If someone have better answer ,I will accept that from my heart.

Comment: WDYT about contributing it to the PHP driver codebase?